# Scroll ul list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scroll the ul list by clicking on top and down arrow.During Scroll it should display only one li element and hide the remaining.  Please, can any one help me in achieving this.For code check the  code pen link

```
<div class="ok-top" id="up"></div>
<div id="list">
<ul class="innerbox">
<li>2001</li>
<li>2002</li>
</ul>
<div class="ok-bottom" id="down"></div>
<div class="boxlines"></div>
```

for full code please check the code pen link

[Code pen link](http://codepen.io/SantoshNeela/pen/dpyaZv)

Comment: Answer to your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var listcount = $('li').size();
var cli = 1;
$('#down').click(function() {
  if (cli < listcount) {
    $('li:nth-child(' + cli + ')').slideToggle();
    cli++;
  }
});
$('#up').click(function() {
  if (cli > 1) {
    cli--;
    $('li:nth-child(' + cli + ')').slideToggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.boxlines {
  width: 60px;
  left: 46px;
  height: 35px;
  border-top: 2px solid #31b6e7;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #31b6e7;
  margin-top: -11px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
}
.innerbox {
  list-style: none;
}
.ok-top {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  left: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #333;
}
.ok-bottom {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 60px;
  bottom: -9px;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}
div#list {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 165px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="ok-top" id="up"></div>

  <div id="list">
    <ul class="innerbox">
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">Select</li>
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">2001</li>
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">2002</li>
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">2003</li>
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">2004</li>
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">2005</li>
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">2006</li>
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">2007</li>
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">2008</li>
      <li style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:24px;">2009</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="boxlines"></div>
  <div class="ok-bottom" id="down"></div>
```